# facebook instant game publishing

Tags: facebook, playcanvas

we are developing a game for Facebook Instant Games Platform (messenger);

The game works fine for developers and testers and is virtually ready for submission; however, when we sent the game for review, the reviewer returned an image with error “Sorry, this feature is not supported in your region yet.” and no further explanation and/or an actual feature, that’s not supported.

The only way, we could replicate the same error was to make the FB app temporarily public and run it from a non-tester, non-developer account, that is not connected to the project in any way. And… F12 (debug tools) gives no actual errors, we don’t see any loading screens, just that message in the middle of a blank black page and no messages from whatever we print for sanity check from the first couple of lines of our index.html file…

We would apprecaiate, if someone with similar experience could help me with some guidance…

Thanks in advance.

Note:
The only external tools our project is using are limited to Firebase and FBInstant API, if that matters;

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/quickstart#app-setup says, _“As Facebook gradually rolls out Instant Games to a wider audience, your game may not be accessible to everyone.”_ - so that is the most likely reason for the error. But the reviewers should have accounts available that are able to properly test this - so this is their mess-up in this instance, I’d say. Maybe submit again and mention this in your review instructions, and ask them to please make sure they test this with an account for which this feature is already available.

Comment: I don't know the exact features that are failing. When we managed to replicate the error, it didn't exactly give us any other errors or leads to follow. So, what features should we mention when we do the resubmission?  @CBroe

Comment: I meant Instant Games in itself, that is a “feature” that is not available everywhere yet, Facebook is rolling it out gradually. The reviewer seems to have tested your app with an account for which simply Instant Games in general are not available yet.

Comment: Can you post the app ID here so we can look into it? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisHawkins. App id is 926615630843478, thank you

Comment: All kind of Facebook/Messenger Instant Games related questions try to ask on https://www.facebook.com/groups/instantgamedevelopers/, because Stack Overflow doesn't work for this niche (unfortunately).